# How can i restrict special characters from being typed and pasted in html text boxes

Tags: jquery, html, mouseevent, keyboard-events

I have a text input box for entering user name. i want to restrict the special characters and numbers from being typed in that box(not showing the error after the submit button click. avoiding typing and pasting from keyboard and mouse). I came across some javascipt codes to restrict on the keyboard and mouse events (like keypress etc.,). but i think there might be better way than doing this by adding some html attributes or by adding some bootstrap framework classes.

I tried the below code (ruby on rails):

```
<%= f.text_field :fname,  required: true, placeholder: "First Name", class: "form-control",:pattern => "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" %>
```

However this is triggering the error after submit button click

I am using JQuery in my application.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please don't post code in the comment section. Please edit your question.

Comment: I don't know if there is a better method than using JS events. I recently answered using `keyup` event in a "similar" question. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49731857/how-can-i-prevent-tilde-in-input/49732153?noredirect=1#comment86478011_49732153)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `input masks`. There are many jquery plugins which will help you do so.

Check this stackoverflow question for demo and answers:

[How to restrict special characters in a certain form field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25448650/how-to-restrict-special-characters-in-a-certain-form-field)